# How to call two instances of same non-global JavaScript function with parameters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call two different instances of a JavaScript function from HTML code, but I am confused about variable scope, the exact details of object instantiation, the necessity of returning the function to the browser, where and how to provide the function's parameters ... I tried different combinations of pieces of code from SO, yet to no avail. I am familiar with OOP, but not in its functional/JavaScript flavour.

I HTML I have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var localInstance = new globalFunction();
    localInstance.localFunction("someString", "someOtherString");

    var otherLocalInstance = new globalFunction();
    otherLocalInstance.localFunction("someString2", "someOtherString2");
</script>
```

In a JavaScript file called "JavaScript.js" I have something like:

```
function globalFunction() {
    var string;
    var otherstring;
    function localFunction(str, ostr) {
        string = str;
        otherstring = ostr;
        // do something more
    }
};
```

I get an `Uncaught TypeError: localInstance.myFunction is not a function` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you declare a function called `myFunction`?

Comment: It doesn't look like you declared "myFunction". It looks like you declared localFunction.

Comment: there's a few things wrong above, but you need to publish in your constructor if you use `new`, then call it as a method, as you do

Comment: Why call `new globalFunction();` in the first place? Why do you need an "instance" here? Why not have a function that accepts two arguments?

Comment: myFunction was what I called localFunction in an earlier draft. Sorry about that.

Comment: `function localFunction() { ... }` is simply a local function inside `globalFunction`. It doesn't automagically become a property of the newly created object. If you want to learn about OOP basics have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html#h_YKXJZqcaJA and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript .

Comment: I believe I need to have instances because I need to use the same function twice (with different parameters, simultaneously).

Comment: There must be hundreds of questions about the confusion between object properties and local variables/functions, but I can't find any of them right now. Hopefully someone else will succeed.

Comment: *"I believe I need to have instances because I need to use the same function twice"* That's the whole point of functions! `function add(x, y) { return x + y; }` can be called as `add(1,2)` or `add(42,41)` whenever and how often you like. There is no need to instantiate anything. Maybe have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html ?

Comment: Your quote misses what I put in brackets: simultaneously. I really don't know about the JS internals, but isn't it possible that the function is called again while its first call is still executing? In my case, localFunction is loading a large JPG into an oversized and a small image (two loading processes). And I need to repeat this. Whenever I try without object instantiation, only one canvas element is shown. When I copy my JS file and change variable names, however, everything works fine (except for the editing of the yet unfinished JS file). Do you have an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to return your function so it can be accessible from the outside , something like this:

```
function globalFunction() {

 var string;
 var otherstring;
 function localFunction(str, ostr) {
    string = str;
    otherstring = ostr;
    // do something more
 }
 return {
  localFunction: localFunction
 }};
```

Comment: Yes, that solved part of the problem. However, I still do not get two different instances of the function. Is this the part about "publish in your constructor if you use ´new´" in the comments above?

Comment: Yes you can get different instance of the function using the keyword `new`, or using `bind` something like:
`var obj = new globalFunction();`
`var instance1 = obj.localFunction.bind(null);`
`var instance2 = obj.localFunction.bind(null);`

Comment: `var obj = new globalFunction();
var instance1 = obj.localFunction.bind(null);
instance1.localFunction("string", "otherstring");`
gives me an `Uncaught TypeError: instance1.localFunction is not a function`

Comment: did you edited your `globalFunction` function like above?

Comment: Yes, and I started to get one instance (again), but in order to have another instance (or real instances at all) I need to do the `new` or `bind` part, the latter of which did not work so far.

Comment: `bind` should give you a new instance of the function. it works just fine for me.